# Data Model for Generating recommendations using Apache Mahout

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, hadoop, mahout, recommendation-engine

I am planning to generate recommendations for the users of my web application. So I decided to use Apache Mahout for it. Most of the tutorials I've seen uses FileDataModel(where the data is stored in a csv file) However my data is in the database.

Is using a FileDataModel for generating user recommendations good enough for a web application that has roughly around 500  to 1000 Users?(I'll just transfer the needed the data from the DB to my CSV file)? or are there any alternatives?

Here are the [first](http://www.philippeadjiman.com/blog/2009/11/11/flexible-collaborative-filtering-in-java-with-mahout-taste/) and [second](https://code.google.com/p/unresyst/wiki/CreateMahoutRecommender) the tutorials I referred to.

Answer (score 2):

Preference data can be accessed from the database using JDBCDataModel.

Take a look at [MySQLJDBCDataModel](https://builds.apache.org/job/Mahout-Quality/javadoc/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/model/jdbc/MySQLJDBCDataModel.html)

Comment: Agree, this is the right answer. At any scale, it will be too slow to read from the database directly. In the end the data must be in memory. For this, see ReloadingJDBCDataModel.

Comment: @SeanOwen what if I have 100 to 1000 users using my application, is this still reliable? assuming there are 100 concurrent users accessing my site

Comment: You can't run the recommender every time you want recommendations for a user. You must use a recommender service which will learn periodically using new data and your webservice should ask for particulally user recommendations

Answer (score 0):

Mahout also has DBDataModels for many other sources, including MongoDBDataModel, and just about any JDBC compliant data source. The flat file data model is also useful for smaller data sets